# How can I add weeks to current date and return a result in the form field?

Tags: javascript, html, datetime, form-fields, ng-app

I am using the following code to display the date in a form.

In the form I have a field titled `"Duration"` being weekly rental eg 3 weeks, 5 weeks etc..

I would like the `"Return Date"` do display the date `"X"` number of weeks from the date the form is filled out, what ever `"Duration"` was selected.
How can I (+ 7) the Date but instead of (+ 7) do a (+ Duration)?

---

ALSO I don't know how to return this `"Date"` to my Excel spread sheet (Google Sheets) All the other fields work fine but I don't know what I am missing or how to return the inline JavaScript result to the excel/google sheets.

---

```
<span id="time" name="time" class="form-control" readonly>

<script type="text/javascript">
var d=new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate() + 7);

var weekday=new Array("Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday",
                "Friday","Saturday")
var monthname=new Array("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug",
                "Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec")
document.write(weekday[d.getDay()] + " ")
document.write(d.getDate() + " ")
document.write(monthname[d.getMonth()] + " ")
document.write(d.getFullYear() + " ")


</script>
</span>

____________________________________________________________________________
```

If you need the whole code I would be happy to share it but have only included the string which I am trying to reflect the current date + Duration in a readonly form field.

Thanks in advance if I don't reply soon.
Jeff

Comment: Watch your spelling of JavaScript, to avoid collision with Java.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to go over it. I am no expert, just mashing code at this stage. Warmest regards, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You can get the next date with duration with this
suppose

```
currentDate = new Date();
```

and

```
duration = 3
```

then the next date

```
const nextdate = new Date(currentDate.getTime() + duration*7*24*60*60*1000);

console.log(nextdate .toLocaleDateString());
```

you can format the date aas string like this

```
const nextDateString= ("0" + resultDate.getDate()).slice(-2) + "/" +("0" + (resultDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "/" + resultDate.getFullYear();
console.log(nextDateString);
```

You can bind the event listner, by which input you are using for duration selection and there you can set this date to value of your readonly input

```
document.getElementById("time").value = nextDate;
```

Comment: Adding days as multiples of 8.64e ms is not a good idea as in places where daylight saving is observed, not all days are 24 hours long. See [*How to add days to Date?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563406/how-to-add-days-to-date)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will try it soon. It isn't Urgent. I appreciate your time. Thank you very much.